# CSS background image not positioning bottom

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm having an odd issue happen when trying to position an SVG at the bottom of a div:

http://jsfiddle.net/GsPhA/2/

The svg source is listed below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="grad" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="0">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#FFF" />
        <stop offset="0.1" stop-color="#FFF" />
        <stop offset="0.5" stop-color="#B1B1B1" />
        <stop offset="0.9" stop-color="#FFF" />
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FFF" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="1px" style="fill:url(#grad)" />
</svg>
```

How can I get the svg to appear below the text (like a border-bottom)?

I'm not entirely fussed about earlier browsers, if it requires CSS 3 properties I'm happy!

**EDIT:** If there is no better way than absolute positioning, I will just add another div below to provide the effect.

**EDIT 2:** I'm not sure what I need to do differently with SVG, but positioning bottom with PNG works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/YXRQX/1/

Is there anything I need to specify in the SVG code so it works properly?

**EDIT 3:** Final working jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/GsPhA/4/ Thank you To Ryan for the pointer!

Comment: Will that div always be that particular height? Or, will it be different in different applications? In other words does it have to be relative to the bottom, or can it be relative to the top?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/skram/GsPhA/3/ - Is this is something that you want?

Comment: I wondered about that. For some reason, I then lost the SVG in your jsfiddle.

Comment: It should just appear at the bottom of the div. Is the SVG written wrong? Or does it just not want to work?

Comment: There is a chance that it might go onto two lines. Plus I have to deal with multiple browsers and text sizes. Is there a better way than absolute positioning?

Comment: It seems the SVG is dynamically sizing to fill whatever space it needs to fill. I don't know how to keep it from doing that, but I think it's the problem here.

Comment: that's a useful pointer Ryan, I'll take a look into this

Comment: Success! `background-size` did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done it! Thanks to Ryan's pointer, I've added the `background-size` css property to fix the size to 1px high:

```
.ucp-controls {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    color: #242424;
    cursor: default;

    background: url('http://priddle.serveblog.net/sums2/images/header/line.png') bottom no-repeat;

    background-size: 100% 1px; // The key line; preserves the width but locks the height.
    font-family: Arial;
}​
```

In the end, the SVG was resizing itself based on the size of the container it was being the background for.

Answer (score 0):

As long as both are in the same container, the text should go above the SVG object like below:

```
<center>
<p>Sample Text Here</p>
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="grad" x1="0" y1="0" x2="100%" y2="0">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#FFF" />
        <stop offset="0.1" stop-color="#FFF" />
        <stop offset="0.5" stop-color="#B1B1B1" />
        <stop offset="0.9" stop-color="#FFF" />
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#FFF" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="1px" style="fill:url(#grad)" />
</svg>
</center>
```

Comment: The SVG is not in the HTML source. It's being used as a background image.